# SSLVerifyClient require in .htaccess on shared host—CVE-2009-3555 mitigation woes

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

After some research I got the idea that I can't use `SSLVerifyClient` successfully anywhere except within a server context because of current CVE-2009-3555 mitigation efforts.

Specifically, because of CVE-2009-3555, various versions of OpenSSL, Apache/mod_ssl and some browsers stopped allowing SSL renegotiation. So `SSLVerifyClient require` in a Directory, Location or .htaccess context causes service to fail (e.g. various of [these examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) fail). Since CVE-2009-3555, RFC 5746 was published, which newer versions of OpenSSL, Apache/mod_ssl etc. support.

Q1: Is this summary approximately correct?

My problem immediate is with shared web hosting. I've no access to httpd.conf and no way to upgrade the software.

Q2: If I find a shared web hosting company running recent software that supports RFC 5746 TLS Renegotiation Indication (unlike GoDaddy) will I have any success putting into .htaccess:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/my/ca.crt
```

where ca.crt is my bastard self-signed CA cert?

[mod_ssl docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) don't say `SSLCACertificateFile` can go in a .htaccess but I don't get the typical "Not allowed here" error when I put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yeah, correct.

Q2: No, I don't think it'll work.

Config-wise, is there any reason `SSLCACertificateFile` couldn't go in a broader config section like a `VirtualHost` block?

But, that aside, client certificates are probably a lost cause on this system, assuming that GoDaddy has actually patched to disable renegotiation (with them, I won't assume).  I don't know of any way around the requirement that client certificate authentication requires a renegotiation.

Comment: It could go in a borader context but I don't believe I have access to any kind of httpd.conf. All I can touch, it seems, is .htaccess.